# How to perform an async task before/after opening a screen in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

Hi I am performing an operation from screen B. After the operation I am showing one alert dialog. Once the user clicks on the OK button in that dialog it will navigates to screen A. It is happening via Intent.

Screen A contains a list. The list is populated via a list activity and an array adapter.

I need to update the list by calling an async task before or after opening the screen A.

How to do it?

Comment: Look into using loaders instead.

Comment: That won't support in 2.2 version right?

Comment: It will. You have to use the support library to do so

Comment: Either you use a loader or AsyncTask you have to update the list before showing it. When you open the Screen A you probably should show a loading spinner, update the data behind the list and as soon as the new data is ready notify the list about it, then hide the loading spinner.

Comment: @dymmeh Instead of going for loader how can I update it?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by instantiating your AsyncTask in your onResume() or onCreate() methods. Then, in doInBackground method of AsyncTask class you could load the data you need for listView in some Array. Finnaly, in onPostExecute() you should instantiate your adapter with data you have in array and then assign it to your listView. Something like this:

```
ProgressDialog pd;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayList<String> dataStrings;

@Override
public void onResume() {
         dataStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
         pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
         new MyAsyncTask().execute(params);
}

public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,  Boolean, ArrayList<String>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute( )
    {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pd.setTitle(EsCache.instance.getLangItem("LABEL_PLEASE_WAIT"));
        pd.setMessage(EsCache.instance.getLangItem("LABEL_LOADING_DATA"));
        pd.setCancelable(true);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               dataStrings = SomeMethodGetData(); // returns data and stores it in list
               return dataStrings;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> list) {
              adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataStrings);

              listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
      pd.dismiss();
    }


}
```

This is just a simplest demonstration, but it gets the job done, it is not much different if you use some custom adapter. You have to be careful though that you don't mixup something and try to change anything that has something to do with UI from doInBackground() :)
I hope that this helps you.